# Getting error while installing SonarQube plugin in eclipse 4.2.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I am trying to install the sonar in my eclipse but it can not find the url even though the url is working fine in my browser. If any one knows the solution please let me know, thanks.

[image: Eclipse - Error Contacting Site]

Answer (score 0):

To install the plugin you can also go to **Help > Eclipse Marketplace**... and search for "SonarQube". Check [this](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  I checked it but getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, the Eclipse SonarQube plugin has been deprecated and SonarLint for Eclipse should be used in place : see http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html

Comment: Tried this one too, but the problem remained same.